# Can't read remote disk on debian

Tags: debian, mount, remote

I have mounted a time capsule on my debian like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.0.0.4/Data /mnt/timeCapsule -o user=Kiva,pass=pass,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm
```

When I do a df, I see the disk:

```
$> df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs            15G  6.7G  7.2G  49% /
/dev/root         15G  6.7G  7.2G  49% /
devtmpfs         428M     0  428M   0% /dev
tmpfs             87M  216K   87M   1% /run
tmpfs            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            173M     0  173M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1    56M   15M   42M  26% /boot
//10.0.0.4/Data  1.9T  1.7T  165G  92% /mnt/timeCapsule
```

But when I do a ls, my host blocks and nothing happens.
I have to kill my session to control again my host.

What's wrong in my mount command ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is tcpdump when I do a ls:

```
16:18:35.401542 IP 10.0.0.8.52416 > 10.0.0.4.445: Flags [P.], seq 2668297578:2668297656, ack 2839374848, win 254, options [nop,nop,TS val 181838028 ecr 14079,nop,nop,sack 1 {1449:1585}], length 78SMB PACKET: SMBtrans2 (REQUEST)

16:18:35.599763 IP 10.0.0.4.445 > 10.0.0.8.52416: Flags [.], ack 78, win 64240, options [nop,nop,TS val 14219 ecr 181838028], length 0
16:18:47.816242 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.2, length 46
16:18:48.621790 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.4 tell 10.0.0.2, length 46
16:18:57.992550 IP 10.0.0.8.52416 > 10.0.0.4.445: Flags [P.], seq 78:120, ack 1, win 254, options [nop,nop,TS val 181840288 ecr 14079,nop,nop,sack 1 {1449:1585}], length 42SMB PACKET: SMBecho (REQUEST)

16:18:58.532439 IP 10.0.0.8.52416 > 10.0.0.4.445: Flags [P.], seq 78:120, ack 1, win 254, options [nop,nop,TS val 181840342 ecr 14079,nop,nop,sack 1 {1449:1585}], length 42SMB PACKET: SMBecho (REQUEST)

16:18:58.533616 IP 10.0.0.4.445 > 10.0.0.8.52416: Flags [.], ack 120, win 64240, options [nop,nop,TS val 14265 ecr 181840288,nop,nop,sack 1 {78:120}], length 0
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at the network traffic with Wireshark or tcpdump?

Comment: I edit my question with tcpdump result